How to automate building Dropdown list in Bluebeam forms
My application requires a custom dropdown list for over 60 drop down options.
Option 1, would like to set up an array that could be pasted into the JavaScript then load the contents of the array in a dropdown form box to display the text from the array on the PDF.
Another option would be to print the value of the variable on the pdf directly. Bluebeam has the "console.println" function but I can find no function that allows me to print a variable value to the PDF.
I am new to JavaScript and have been learning online.  I have had success turning on layers with a binary nested array constructed from a matrix in an Excell spreadsheet to display the correct layer based on the dropdown box selection.
In my application there are multiple steps and a combination of layers are turned on and off for each step. Currently my step descriptions are " Step 1, Step 2, Step 3".  I would like to add a description for example: "Step 1 Pre Rinse"
Step descriptions will be different for each customer and some customers may have 50 or more individual step descriptions so it is not realistic to enter the dropdown data manually. I am open to whatever help or direction you can provide.
I thought this would work but have been unable to get it to work in Bluebeam.
I receive a message   "undefined"

Thank you,
The snippet you sent works.  I just need to incorporate into my document.
Tim

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
